# FilePicker.platform.pickFiles() does not show dialog from Futurebuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder, filepicker

My code is as follows:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';

void main() {
  return runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late final Future<void> _initializeController = Future<void>(() async {
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(); // <= no dialog here !!!
    print('picked');
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _initializeController,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return MaterialApp(
              home: SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
                body: Center(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  FilePickerResult? result =
                      await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(); // <= dialog pops here
                },
                child: const Text("Press"),
              ),
            )),
          ));
        } else {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that `pickFiles()` not showing dialog when called from `FutureBuilder` `future` function. No error appears. It happens on web. Tried on Android - `pickFiles` works as expected.

How could I call filepicker from futurebuilder? I need to show the filepicker dialog on the widget initialization